# Understanding the statement and the proof of Bertini's theorem in Griffiths and Harris

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, intersection-theory

I am having trouble understanding the statement and the proof of Bertini's theorem in Griffiths & Harris book (p.$137$). Frankly, I do not understand a word even after I read several answers on stack. The theorem is

> *The generic element of a linear system is smooth away from the base locus of the system.*

**First question**. *Does the statement above refer to linear of general line bundles rather than just line bundles associated to divisors?*

As far as I can say, it refers to a linear system of a line bundle associated to a divisor. Tell me if I am wrong.

**Second question**. *What is the generic element? Or what is the generic pencil?*

In the proof, the authors start with "*If the generic element of a linear system is singular away from the base locus of the system, then the same will be true for a generic pencil contained in the system; thus it suffices to prove Bertini for a pencil.*"

**Third question**. *What does the above sentence mean exactly?*

Now suppose $\left \{D_{\lambda} \right \}_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^1}$ is a pencil

**Fourth question**. *Why do the authors write $D_{\lambda} = (f+\lambda g = 0)$? What do $f,g$ mean here?*

The last question relates to the degree of a variety (p.$171$).

> Bertini applied to the smooth locus of $V$ the generic $(n-k)$-plane $\mathbb{P}^{n-k} \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ will intersect $V$ transversely and so will meet $V$ in exactly $\mathrm{deg}(V) = ^{\#}(\mathbb{P}^{n-k}.V)$ points.

**Last question**. *What is generic $(n-k)$-plane? In this case, why does it intersect $V$ transversely?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your setting (a complex manifold) all line bundles come from divisors and vice-versa.
2. A generic element of a linear system means that in the $\mathbb P^r$ parametrizing members of that linear system, we consider some dense open subset of $\mathbb P^r$. Generic elements are those parametrized by a point in that dense open. A generic pencil similarly parametrized by a point in a dense open of the Grassmannian $G(2,r+1)$ of $2$-dimensional subspaces of $H^0(L)$ (where $L$ is the line bundle).
3. The sentence is saying that any "bad" behavior will occur in a pencil, so we don't need to worry about higher-dimensional linear systems.
4. They mean $f,g \in H^0(L)$, so taking linear combinations of $f$ and $g$ yields a pencil.
5. A generic plane is parametrized by a dense open subset of the appropriate Grassmannian. The transversality is because transversality is an open condition.

Comment: 3) I wonder about the possibility of this reduction, would you mind to formulate this and the 'open condition' in 5)?  4) As fas as I understand, f,g stand for two generators of global sections $H^0(L)$.

Comment: There's not really anything more I can think to say. If most points of $\mathbb P^r$ parametrize singular divisors, then in particular most points of a randomly chosen line in $\mathbb P^r$ will parametrize singular divisors. As for 5), I don't think I can say anything more explicit; the subset of planes that don't meet $V$ transversely is a closed subset (I suppose there's some Jacobian determinant one could write down that cuts out the this subset).